# How to reinstall visual studio and change path it goes to

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to install Visual Studio to my external hard drive after I uninstalled the program. I'd give a visual(ha, puns), but my camera isn't working, but my problem is: When I try to change the path, it does nothing. I tried getting the installer again, but same thing. Is there a fix for this problem or am I stuck with Visual Studio on this computer forever?

Comment: you're installing visual studio... and want to take a picture of your monitor with a camera?  Are you unfamiliar with taking screen shots? http://www.take-a-screenshot.org/

Comment: You can most definitely change the path VS installs to, but I'm not sure how someone could help you with the information that has been provided.  http://www.placona.co.uk/1196/dotnet/installing-visual-studio-on-a-different-drive/

Comment: I suggest you look at everything on your hard disk, and sort it by how easy it will be to install to another disk, and put visual studio at the very bottom of the disk. Visual studio is at least 90% other components which aren't wanting to go to another disk. Focus on other programs first if you want to clear up space.